# For each over an array using handlebar-helpers

Tags: arrays, node.js, handlebars.js, express-handlebars, handlebarshelper

i have done `groupBy` on Name and Time and output array below and i want to loop through in node using handlebar-helpers.and after every group/index i want to page break.

any suggestions?

i have used below code in report.

```
{{#each List}}
 <tr> 
  <td>
   {{#if name}} <div>{{name}}</div> {{/if}} 
  </td>
  <td>
   {{#if time}} <div>{{time}}</div> {{/if}} 
  </td> 
 </tr> 
{{/each}}

<div style="page-break-before:always;">

List: 

[ { name: "vinay", time: 1 },{ name: "vinay", time: 1 } ], 
[ { name: "vinay", time: 2 } ],
[ { name: "prats", time: 1 } ], 
[ { name: "prats", time: 4 } ], 
[ { name: "swapnil", time: 5 } ], 
[ { name: "swapnil", time: 5 } ]
```

Comment: Can you please explain your question in  more detail ?  I can help, but I have not understood the question exactly

Comment: Please make your code more readable if you want an answer. I have done this for you. 
I am not certain what you try to achieve here. In my opinion your "list" should be formatted cleaner.